# How to get latest DETAIL entry against the MASTER entry?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables

**1. User Master**
user_id, user_full_name, user_dob...so on

**2. Login Details**
login_id, login_user_id, login_time, login_date, logout_time

***Problem***

2nd table has n number of rows against User Master table id

I need to make a join but the condition is that it should show only last login data of the user

example
user_full_name, user_login, user_logout so on...

Comment: Do you want that for a specific user, or all users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the result for a single user, you could use a simple `INNER JOIN` combined with an `ORDER BY` and `TOP 1`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 user_full_name, login_time, login_date, logout_time
FROM Users INNER JOIN Logins ON
  Users.user_id = Logins.user_id
WHERE
  Users.user_id = @user_id
ORDER BY login_date DESC, login_time DESC
```

(See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c76c/1))

If you want the result for all users, you could use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT user_full_name, l.*
FROM Users u CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 login_time, login_date, logout_time
  FROM Logins
  WHERE
    u.user_id = Logins.user_id
  ORDER BY login_date DESC, login_time DESC
  ) l
```

(See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c76c/5))

Answer (score 1):

A common solution for this problem is to use the `row_number` window function and filter for rows with row number 1 in each partition (by user, ordered by date/time):

```
WITH UserDetails AS (
    SELECT 
       *
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY login_user_id 
                            ORDER BY login_date DESC, login_time DESC) AS RN
    FROM LoginDetails
)
SELECT * 
FROM UserMaster  M
JOIN UserDetails D ON M.user_id = D.login_user_id
WHERE D.RN = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a TOP 1 inside the JOIN clause:

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.user_full_name, b.login_id...
FROM UserMaster a INNER JOIN Logins b ON b.login_date =
(
    SELECT  TOP 1 login_date 
    FROM    Logins 
    WHERE   login_user_id = a.user_id
    ORDER BY login_date DESC
)
```